# Storing list in a list within for loop in R

Tags: r

I am trying to store a list within a list in a way that I can access it by list ID just like Python dictionary:

```
idList <- list('A','B','C','D','E')

subnet <- list('A'=0,'B'=0,'C'=0,'D'=0,'E'=0)


for (ids in idList) {
 
  tmp <- c('some','random','list')

 subnet$ids <- tmp

}
```

But when I check the results as `subnet$A` I get the value `0`

I am not able to understand why the `tmp` value is not being stored in the `subnet` list?

When I do it on the command line individually, then it works:

```
   R> subnet$A <- tmp
   R> subnet$A
   R> "some" "random" "list"
```

To me R is weird and it works in a completely unintuitive way.

Comment: Use `subnet[[ids]] <- tmp`

Comment: I think you want `subnet[[ids]]` instead of  `subnet$ids`. The `list$var` syntax is literally using the name `var` to access the list element. It is not evaluating `var` to a character. The `list[[var]]` will evaluate `var` to the character.

Comment: But can you explain why it works when I try to run it individually on R- console ? I mean the same ```subnet$ids <- tmp``` assigns value to it when run on console